# Static binding vs Dynamic binding

Tags: java, dynamic, binding, static, overloading

Hi I don't know how the compiler determine which method executes. I know that there is the compile time and the execution time. We have overloading methods.

```
public class A{
    void print(A x){
        System.out.println("This is message A");
    }
}

public class B extends A{
    void print (B x){
        System.out.println("This is message B");
    }
}

A a = new A();
B b = new B();
A ab = new B();
b.print(a);
b.print(ab);
```

In both calls the results are:

This is message A

Comment: what's `b.f` ? there is no such method ...

Comment: I think the method f is nothing but print? If that's the case, you are passing a and ab both of which are declared as type A. So it will always invoke void print(A x) since it accepts an object of type A

Comment: don't confuse overloading with overriding. these are two different OO concepts. you will override a method in a subclass if it has the same signature as the one in the super.

Answer (score 1):

This is neither overloading nor overriding. And secondly, you cannot point to parent object with child reference

Comment: Yes it's is overloading. Method print. Same name different parameters

Comment: for overloading, methods  should be in a same class with same methods name with different argument type and number.

Answer (score -2):

There is no dynamic binding in Java. all method calls are resolved during compile time (unless one uses reflection, which is not the case here)

However, the `print()` method of class `B` does not override the one from class `A`, since the arguments do not have the same type. Also, what matters for the compiler is the formal declaration of a variable, not its assignment. Therefor, ab variable is referred to as an Object of `A` type. so the compiler will call the `print()` of `A` class, since it is not overriden in `B`

Comment: Java supports dynamic (run-time) binding. Polymorphism is dynamic binding. You can't create an abstract method in an abstract base class without dynamic binding.